# Receiving request from php to android

Tags: php, android, wamp

```
package com.sunil.phpconnect;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpGet request;
    HttpResponse response;
    String url;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // URL of PHP Script

        url = "http://192.168.3.103/index.php";

        // TextView to display result

        TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        // Try to connect using Apache HttpClient Library
        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            request = new HttpGet(url);
            response = httpclient.execute(request);
            }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // response code
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    response.getEntity().getContent()));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {

                // Appending result to textview
                result.append(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Second Exception", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**I am not able to receive request from my php file containing**

```
<?php
echo "Hello PHP";
?>
```

**What is the problem in the code?
I am sending Http request to php file but not receiving the required result.
According to me i think there is problem in URL.
Give me suggestions**

**MY LOGCAT**

```
08-05 05:07:30.311: W/System.err(2009): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-05 05:07:30.321: W/System.err(2009):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-05 05:07:30.331: W/System.err(2009):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-05 05:07:30.341: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-05 05:07:30.361: W/System.err(2009):     at com.sunil.phpconnect.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 05:07:30.381: W/System.err(2009):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-05 05:07:30.393: W/System.err(2009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-05 05:07:30.401: W/System.err(2009):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-05 05:07:30.401: W/System.err(2009):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: there there any exception

Comment: my log cat  :  https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=7BEB3A827335E4F7!2034&authkey=!AGA8dcNFGhEVJTM

Comment: used this and worked
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are using higher sdk version used this following code

```
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
                StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
```

Comment: this is bad practice you shouldn't be promoting this type of practice

Answer (score 0):

Aamir,
try not using the 
`http://127.0.0.1/` URL, from your Android device this will be pointing to Android's localhost which I assume is not where your PHP file is. If the device and php server are on the same local network use your local IP address instead.

Comment: i have used this ip address (url = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";) in my emulator browser it is working but not in my code. It is moving to first catch block.Why

Comment: used this and worked
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Use **ipaddress** instead of **127.0.0.1** or **localhost**.

in command prompt type **ipconfig** and get your **ipaddress**.

Comment: i have used this ip address (url = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";) in my emulator browser it is working but not in my code. It is moving to first catch block.Why?

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is your ip address?

Comment: i am using emulator and getting results. Which means there is no issu of internet
My logcat : http://sdrv.ms/16tTmpi

Comment: 10.0.2.2 is my ip address

Comment: if you are using emulator but you have to provide your current ipaddress when you want to use file like index.php ( from localhost) i have did same mistake earlier.

Comment: just get your ipaddress ( ipv4 ) and set it instead of 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.2.2

Comment: Not working
I have edited the code check it again
It displays toast written First Exception

Comment: 1) open google type "what is my ipaddress" and use that ipaddress

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34813/discussion-between-butani-vijay-and-aamir-mukaram)

Comment: used this and worked
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your manifest file, that you have implement INTERNET permissions for it or not?

Comment: Yes i have given permission for internet

Answer (score 0):

use `ip address 10.0.2.2 instead of 127.0.0.1`

so try by changing to

```
url = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";
```

**PS.**

either use `AysncTask`

or add following code in your `onCreate()`    after     `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                    .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Comment: i have used this ip address (url = "http://10.0.2.2/index.php";) in my emulator browser it is working but not in my code. It is moving to first catch block.Why

Comment: @AamirMukaram `print stacktrace in your that catch block and post it to your question`  to print stack trace use `e.printStackTrace();` inside catch block !

Comment: I am using android for a week i have written this e.printStackTrace();
in my catch block now what to do. What i have to post

Comment: @AamirMukaram than what are you getting in logcat ?

Comment: @AamirMukaram sorry i can access limited sites as i am at office so plz post log cat with your question !

Comment: check i have copied the logcat above

Comment: @AamirMukaram welcome :) now you can mark my answer as accepted by clicking on tick arrow of my answer ! also you can upvote by clicking on up arrow !

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is your performing network activity on the main thread.

```
08-05 05:07:30.311: W/System.err(2009): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

This type of behavior can lead to ANR (Activity Not responding) because the UI thread gets blocked with I/O activity. Your suggested to use `AsyncTask` to perform this.